# Get custom fields values in filter on wp_insert_post_data

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, advanced-custom-fields

**Hi all**, thanks for reading.

---

**Environment** :

Wordpress + Advanced Custom Fields plugin

---

**Problem :**

I have searched for hours now and I can't seem to find the correct syntax to do the following:

**When posting a new post, get custom field value in order to automatically replace the title of the post by that value.** Example: I create a post and set '10am' in my 'time' custom field. The title of the post is automatically replaced by '10am'.

---

**Example:**

So I'm adding a filter with the following :

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'change_title') ;

function change_title($data)

{

    $time = XXX ; // How should I get this custom field value ?

    $new_title = 'Topic created at'.$time ;

    $data['post_title'] = $time ;

    return $data;

}
```

---

It must be very simple but I have tried every function available on both WP and the plugin's documentations. I would be **very thankful** if anyone passing by gave me the solution.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually access the global $_POST variable for your field value , but i guess you can do it in a cleaner way by using the save_post action to update your post's title, eg:

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_title');

function change_title($post_id) {
    $time = get_field('time',$post_id);
    $post_title = 'Topic created at '. $time;

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'change_title');

    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_title' => $post_title));

    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'change_title');
}
```

assuming that your ACF fieldname is "time".

Edit: Updated the answer as per Mark Chitty's answer.

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot ! For my knowledge, if I understand correctly in your suggestion we update the post after it was created while in mine I was trying to fetch a custom field while the post hadn't been created yet, correct?

Comment: This will cause infinite loop.

Answer (score 10):

Tweak to Riadh's accepted answer (would add as a comment but haven't got enough rep yet):

As documented in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops) `wp_update_post` includes the `save_post` hook so calling `wp_update_post()` inside the `save_post` hook creates an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook then rehook your function like so:

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_title');

function change_title($post_id) {
    $time = get_field('time',$post_id);
    $post_title = 'Topic created at '. $time;

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'change_title');

    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_title' => $post_title));

    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'change_title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'change_title', '99', 2 );

function change_title($data , $postarr){

    $custom_field = 'custom_filed_name';
    $post_id = $postarr['ID'];
    $time = get_post_meta( $post_id, $custom_field, true );

    // Now you have the value, do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: This doesn't get the custom field for newly created posts. It only works when an existing post is being updated.

Comment: Yes it won't, `save_post` is appropriate hook to do that  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Custom Fields creates a 'field key' for each custom field that is created. I was able to refer to this key value when trying to access the custom fields. The field key value can be found by viewing page source when viewing the post type within the Wordpress admin section.

Look for `data-field-key`. You will see a value similar to `data-field-key="field_5847b00820f13"` in the page source. Use this value when accessing the value in the `$postarr` argument in the `wp_insert_post_data` filter.  The custom fields will be in a nested array named `fields` within the `$postarr` argument.

Alternatively, the field key value can be located by navigating to the Advanced Custom Fields / Export option from within the admin section.  Once you are on the export page for Advanced Custom Fields, select the export to PHP option and you will see the value in the resulting PHP code.

In the example below, I am concatenating two Advanced Custom Fields and updating the `post_title` in the `$data` array returned from the function.

The result is that the `post_title` value will be saved to the database via the built in Wordpress save post logic.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'slb_set_title', '99', 2);

function slb_set_title ($data, $postarr){
  if($data['post_type']==='slb_subscriber'){
    $data['post_title'] = $postarr['fields']['field_5847b00820f13'] .' '.       
    $postarr['fields']['field_5847b03f20f14'];
  }
return $data;
}
```